# Can't take a single value out of Json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-3.4, telegram

So I'm working around with a JSON the Telegram API is giving me. I'm trying to get the message value into a string.

Here is my Json.

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "update_id": 855636291,
            "message": {
                "message_id": 71,
                "from": {
                    "id": 1337,
                    "first_name": "*",
                    "last_name": "*",
                    "username": "*"
                },
                "chat": {
                    "id": 1337,
                    "first_name": "*",
                    "last_name": "*",
                    "username": "*"
                },
                "date": 1435987802,
                "text": "Testing"
            }
        }
    ]
    }
```

Code I'm trying to use to get the value. (Using Requests btw)

```
content = json.loads(r)
msg = content['result'][0]['message'][0]['text]
```

However, it doesn't work. I managed to retrieve the `update_id` with `content['result'][0]['update_id']` but I have no idea on how to retrieve the `text`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `content['result'][0]['message']["text"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message` is not a list, `text` is a key directly in it:

```
msg = content['result'][0]['message']['text']
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `[0]` after `['message']`

```
msg = content['result'][0]['message']['text']
```

Here `message` is a dictionary and `text` is a key which is in that dictionary. Just access `text` as you would normally in a dictionary.